# Visual Studio Shortcut keys for Bookmarks

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper, keyboard-shortcuts

I was trying to practice keyboard shortcuts to become a more productive programmer.  I came across a shortcut that said Toggle Bookmark is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>K</kbd>.  But in my environment the shortcut key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.

I am trying to figure out what is causing this difference?
I am running Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 with ReSharper 9.2 working in a C# web project
I doubt the website is wrong because other websites say the same thing.

Source:
http://visualstudioshortcuts.com/2015/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Different keyboard mapping schemes have different shortcuts, you set the one you want in the keyboard options: the default scheme uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for toggling bookmarks, so you have yours set to one of the others, probably "Visual C# 2005" as per ["Bookmark Window Shortcut Keys, Visual C# Scheme"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366751%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

[image]

Comment: That's the screen I was looking for, and I was on c# 2005.  Thank you... have to wait 5 minutes to accept answer

Comment: It's been a long time since I used that scheme, but I do seem to remember there were lots of differences, eg 'Build' is `Ctrl-Shift-B`  rather than `F6` in the default scheme.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe it's just a mistake in source? Never actually need this shortcut, but tried 
<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> instead of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, and it works

Comment: typo on my part